# char array with variable length

Tags: java, arrays, string, compiler-errors, runtime

How should i declare a char array whose size ranges from 1 to 100 and I cannot make an array of size 100 because i have to make many arrays.
My input is:

```
"bjomboleji";
"bnmjsjbfhaihfaihfga";
"zbihgfbjbnsdfbnbfkj";
"bnxbz";
```

and i have to check the common occurence of characters.

Comment: Please explain a bit more about your inputs.

Comment: If you're used to C or C++, then realize that Java very rarely uses character arrays. Strings are almost always preferred.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. At what point do you know how large the character array needs to be? Are you sure you need an array rather than a string anyway?

Comment: Noone told you about strings?

Comment: I have to check the presence of common characters in the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

```
List<Chracter> array = new ArrayList<Chracter>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `String` to assign the value, then use `toCharArray` to convert to an array (if you really need a character array)

Comment: Yeah i do need to use each characters. And i cannnot possibly make character array for the whole 100 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). It is a "mutable sequence of characters."

This is a better solution than a `List<Character>` as it avoids the need to create `Character` objects from `char` primitives.

This is a better choice than manipulating a `String` as `String` objects are immutable and manipulation results in additional objects being created.

Comment: *it avoids the need to create Character objects from char primitives.* have you heard about [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)?

Comment: @Braj That is just syntactical sugar where the objects are created/obtained on your behalf. It does not avoid the actual creation/use of objects. The actual byte code results in calls to Character.valueOf.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you need to count occurrences of a character in a string.If that's the case here is an example. there is no need to convert it to char array

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x="dhakjkfhajfhuagjkadmnfd";
    String y="tskashguadmnsdm,as";

    String Check_Character="s";

    //Availability
    System.out.println("X has Check_Character :"+x.contains(Check_Character)); //false
    System.out.println("Y has Check_Character :"+y.contains(Check_Character));//true

    //Number of occurrences
    System.out.println("X has Check_Character :"+((x+" ").split(Check_Character).length-1)+" : times");//0 times
    System.out.println("Y has Check_Character :"+((y+" ").split(Check_Character).length-1)+" : times");//4times

} 
}
```

Otherwise you can use a list instead of an array or use this.

```
String z="dhakjkfhajfhuagjkadmnfd";
    char c[]=z.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable length `char` is basically `interface CharSequence` which is implemented by `String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer`. So you can use any of it for variable `char array`.